# Using NEAT can I get a better result for snake game?

Tags: python, neat

I have created snake game in python and am using NEAT to create an Neural network to play the game. I have put a lot of time into playing around with the config file and fitness functions but the average fitness doesn't increase. I would really love if someone could give some advice.

I have attached the python file for the game and also the NEAT config file I used and commented the code for readability.

```
import os
import random
import pygame
import neat
from scipy.spatial import distance

gen = 0
snakes = []
snacks = []
rows = 20


def draw_grid(w, surface):
    size_btwn = w // rows

    x, y = 0, 0
    for l in range(rows):
        x = x + size_btwn
        y = y + size_btwn

        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255, 255, 255), (x, 0), (x, w))
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255, 255, 255), (0, y), (w, y))


def redraw_window(surface):
    global rows, snakes, snacks
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for i, s1 in enumerate(snakes):
        s1.draw(surface)
        s1.snack.draw(surface)
    draw_grid(width, surface)
    pygame.display.update()


class Cube:
    rows = 20
    w = 500

    def __init__(self, position, color=(255, 0, 0)):
        self.pos = position
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, surface):
        dis = self.w // self.rows
        i = self.pos[0]
        j = self.pos[1]

        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, (i * dis + 1, j * dis + 1, dis - 2, dis - 2))


class Snake:

    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.head = Cube(pos)
        self.body = []
        self.body.append(self.head)
        self.dirnx = 0
        self.dirny = 1
        self.added_cube = False
        self.snack = Cube(randomSnack(rows), color=(0, 255, 0))
        self.time = 50

    def change_dir(self, direction_x, direction_y):
        self.dirnx = direction_x
        self.dirny = direction_y

    def move(self):
        self.head = self.body[-1]
        # new_x, new_y = (self.head.pos[0] + self.dirnx) % rows, (self.head.pos[1] + self.dirny) % rows     # add this to stop death from wall hit
        new_x, new_y = (self.head.pos[0] + self.dirnx), (self.head.pos[1] + self.dirny)
        c1 = Cube([new_x, new_y])
        self.body.append(c1)
        if not self.added_cube:
            del self.body[0]
        self.added_cube = False

    def add_cube(self):
        self.added_cube = True

    def draw(self, surface):
        for i, cube in enumerate(self.body):
            cube.draw(surface)


def randomSnack(rows):
    x = random.randrange(rows)
    y = random.randrange(rows)

    return [x, y]


def check_dir_changed():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        for snake in snakes:
            for key in keys:
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    snake.change_dir(-1, 0)

                elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    snake.change_dir(1, 0)

                elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    snake.change_dir(0, -1)

                elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    snake.change_dir(0, 1)


def eval_genomes(genomes, config):
    global width, rows, snakes, snacks, gen
    gen += 1
    width = 500
    rows = 20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))

    nets = []
    snakes = []
    snacks = []
    ge = []

    for genome_id, genome in genomes:
        genome.fitness = 1  # start with fitness level of 1
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(genome, config)
        nets.append(net)
        start_position_x, start_position_y = random.randrange(0, 20), random.randrange(0, 20)
        snakes.append(Snake([start_position_x, start_position_y]))
        ge.append(genome)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True and len(snakes) > 0:
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(10)

        check_dir_changed()
        for i, snake in enumerate(snakes):

            # send info and determine from network what direction to go
            output = nets[snakes.index(snake)].activate(
                (snake.dirnx, snake.dirny, snake.snack.pos[0], snake.snack.pos[1],
                 snake.head.pos[0], snake.head.pos[1], distance.euclidean(snake.snack.pos, snake.head.pos),
                 distance.euclidean(snake.snack.pos[0], snake.head.pos[0]),
                 distance.euclidean(snake.snack.pos[1], snake.head.pos[1])))

            # get the right move to make
            max_output = -2
            best_output = 0
            for j, out in enumerate(output):
                if out > max_output:
                    max_output = out
                    best_output = j

            # 0 is right, 1 is left, 2 is down, 3 is up
            if best_output == 0:
                snake.change_dir(1, 0)
            elif best_output == 1:
                snake.change_dir(-1, 0)
            elif best_output == 2:
                snake.change_dir(0, 1)
            elif best_output == 3:
                snake.change_dir(0, -1)

            snake.move()
            # take 1 from the current snake's time, this stops snakes running around forever
            snake.time -= 1

            # add fitness depending how close snake is to the snack
            ge[snakes.index(snake)].fitness += 20 - distance.euclidean(snake.snack.pos, snake.head.pos)

            # if snake head eats snack
            if snake.body[-1].pos == snake.snack.pos:
                ge[snakes.index(snake)].fitness += 1000
                snake.time += 40    # give snake more time since they got a snack
                snake.add_cube()
                snake.snack = Cube(randomSnack(rows), color=(0, 255, 0))

            # if snake ran out of time without getting snack
            if snake.time < 1:
                ge[snakes.index(snake)].fitness -= 5
                nets.pop(snakes.index(snake))
                ge.pop(snakes.index(snake))
                snakes.pop(snakes.index(snake))
                break

            # if snake hits a wall
            if snake.body[-1].pos[0] > 20 or snake.body[-1].pos[0] < 0 or snake.body[-1].pos[1] > 20 or snake.body[-1].pos[1] < 0:
                ge[snakes.index(snake)].fitness -= 1000
                nets.pop(snakes.index(snake))
                ge.pop(snakes.index(snake))
                snakes.pop(snakes.index(snake))
                break

            # if snake eats itself
            for x in range(len(snake.body) - 1):
                if snake.body[x].pos == snake.body[-1].pos:
                    ge[snakes.index(snake)].fitness -= 10
                    nets.pop(snakes.index(snake))
                    ge.pop(snakes.index(snake))
                    snakes.pop(snakes.index(snake))
                    print('Score: ', len(snake.body))
                    break

        redraw_window(win)

    pass


def run(config_file):
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                                neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                                config_file)

    # Create the population, which is the top-level object for a NEAT run.
    p = neat.Population(config)

    # Add a stdout reporter to show progress in the terminal.
    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stats)
    # p.add_reporter(neat.Checkpointer(5))

    # Run for up to 50 generations.
    winner = p.run(eval_genomes, 100)

    # show final stats
    print('\nBest genome:\n{!s}'.format(winner))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'config-feedforward.txt')
    run(config_path)


[NEAT]
fitness_criterion     = max
fitness_threshold     = 10000000
pop_size              = 20
reset_on_extinction   = True

[DefaultGenome]
# node activation options
activation_default      = sigmoid
activation_mutate_rate  = 0.05
activation_options      = sigmoid gauss
#abs clamped cube exp gauss hat identity inv log relu sigmoid sin softplus square tanh

# node aggregation options
aggregation_default     = random
aggregation_mutate_rate = 0.05
aggregation_options     = sum product min max mean median maxabs

# node bias options
bias_init_mean          = 0.05
bias_init_stdev         = 1.0
bias_max_value          = 30.0
bias_min_value          = -30.0
bias_mutate_power       = 0.5
bias_mutate_rate        = 0.7
bias_replace_rate       = 0.1

# genome compatibility options
compatibility_disjoint_coefficient = 1.0
compatibility_weight_coefficient   = 0.5

# connection add/remove rates
conn_add_prob           = 0.5
conn_delete_prob        = 0.5

# connection enable options
enabled_default         = True
enabled_mutate_rate     = 0.5

feed_forward            = False
#initial_connection      = unconnected
initial_connection      = partial_nodirect 0.5

# node add/remove rates
node_add_prob           = 0.5
node_delete_prob        = 0.2

# network parameters
num_hidden              = 0
num_inputs              = 9
num_outputs             = 4

# node response options
response_init_mean      = 1.0
response_init_stdev     = 0.05
response_max_value      = 30.0
response_min_value      = -30.0
response_mutate_power   = 0.1
response_mutate_rate    = 0.75
response_replace_rate   = 0.1

# connection weight options
weight_init_mean        = 0.1
weight_init_stdev       = 1.0
weight_max_value        = 30
weight_min_value        = -30
weight_mutate_power     = 0.5
weight_mutate_rate      = 0.8
weight_replace_rate     = 0.1

[DefaultSpeciesSet]
compatibility_threshold = 2.5

[DefaultStagnation]
species_fitness_func = max
max_stagnation       = 50
species_elitism      = 0

[DefaultReproduction]
elitism            = 3
survival_threshold = 0.3
```

Comment: Could you should an example of your training progress? Does the fitness get better at all then seem to stagnate, or never improve? Was fitness function values are you typically getting?

Comment: The fitness does not improve at all even from the first generation. I have run it with populations ranging from 2-1000 and generations from 10 to 1000. It seems like the ability does not improve whatsoever from the first generation